# new lwc:ref does not work

Tags: lightning-web-components, reference

I am refactoring our codebase with the new [lwc:ref](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_dom_work) approach, and it just does not work for me.

I've even copy/pasted the code from the [release docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_templaterefs.htm&release=242&type=5) and still getting undefined.

```html
<template>
    <div lwc:ref="myDiv"></div>
</template>
```

```js
export default class extends LightningElement {
  renderedCallback() {
    console.log(this.refs.myDiv);
  }
}
```

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'myDiv')
```

Does not work with old components where I've bumped the api version to 57, neither with new components on the same version.

Comment: case with sf support created

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after some conversation with sf support we found out that the LWS needs to be enabled in order for this feature to work.

> Setup > Session Setting > Lightning Web Security > Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning web components (GA) and Aura components (Beta)